# how to export magento Cron job list?

Tags: magento2, magento-cron

Is there anyway to export the Magento cron job in a list? If possible, including the schedule will be prefect. thanks

Comment: all Magento cron jobs ?

Comment: yes, I need the magento cron job list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all scheduled cronjobs from database by using this query

```
SELECT c.job_code, c.scheduled_at FROM cron_schedule c 
WHERE c.`status` = 'pending'
GROUP BY c.job_code;
```

From above query you can find cronjob name with next scheduled timing.
For proper scheduling of cron you can find in your code with `job_code`. The scheduling will be in `cronjob.xml` file of module.

It is better to use IDE that finds sting in code, and you will be able to find it

Comment: Thanks! is it the job status = pending  is include all the cron job? or just the job still pending? and they are not include running or success cron job?

Comment: This will show all the cronjobs, actually if cronjob is active, it will always appear in pending jobs, so that next time it will run on schedule

Comment: Or else, you can remove pending status from query and compare both list